# How to add multiple products into one cart from different tables

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, cart

I want to add different items into one cart from three different tables like menu,additionalitems and deals.

In the given picture Chicken burger is coming from menu table and fetching ketchup from additionalitems table.

I am able to add multiple items and it's price from menu table but when I resue the same code to add the items like ketchup from additionalitems table into cart it adds the chicken burger into cart instead of ketchup.

Moreover when I create another function to add the ketchup from additional item table into same cart where chicken burger already added code mix the models and only add one item into cart it depends on sequence.

I hope you guys understand my issue so please guide me how to add multiple items into one cart from three different tables.

[image]

```
public function getAddToCart( Request $request, $id ) {
    $product = Menu::find( $id );
    $oldCart = Session::has( 'cart' ) ? Session::get( 'cart' ) : null;
    $cart    = new Cart( $oldCart );
    $cart->add( $product, $product->id );
    $request->session()->put( 'cart', $cart );
    
    // dd($request->session()->get('cart'));
    return redirect()->route( 'pages.menu', $id );
}
```

Above code is used to add items from menu table like chicken burger into cart and beow code is used to add items from additionalitems tabel into cart like Ketchup

```
public function getAddToNewCart( Request $request, $id ) {
    $product = AdditionalItems::find( $id );
    //dd($product);
    $oldCart = Session::has( 'cart' ) ? Session::get( 'cart' ) : null;
    $cart    = new Cart( $oldCart );
    $cart->add( $product, $product->id );
    
    $request->session()->put( 'cart', $cart );
    dd( $request->session()->get( 'cart' ) );
    
    return redirect()->route( 'pages.menu', $id );
}
```

it's add function in the cart model

```
 public function add($item, $id){
        $storedItem = ['qty'=>0,'price'=>$item->price,'item'=> $item];
        if($this->items){
            if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
                $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
            }
        }
        $storedItem['qty'] ++;
        $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
        $this->items[$id] = $storedItem;
        $this->totalQty ++;
        $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
       }
```

Comment: Can you show your method `$cart->add` ? Because I suspect a problem with the ID of each of the items in the cart. Why ? Because you're retrieving a record from the table menu with its own ID handling and the same for the table additionalItem which mean that in your case, some products in your cart can have the same ID without being the same product actually, and that would explain the undefined behavior you're experiencing due to the fact that in some conditions, you have two products with ID 1 and 2 but in another conditions, you have two products with ID 1.

Comment: @bjovanov i added the add function which is used to add items from menu table. please check it

Answer (score 1):

That's what I thought, you have a problem with IDs of the `menu` and `additional_items` tables that can't work together.

For example, if your `menu` table looks like this:

```
+----+-----------+
| ID |   Item    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Hamburger |
+----+-----------+
```

And your `additional_item` like this:

```
+----+-----------+
| ID |   Item    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Ketchup   |
|  2 | Fanta     |
+----+-----------+
```

When you will add Hamburger with `$card->add($product, $product->id)`, everything will be fine because there is only one item with `ID` to 1.

But as soon as you will add Ketchup with `$card->add($product, $product->id)`, since Ketchup has `ID` to 1 in `additional_items` and due to this condition,

```
if(array_key_exists($id, $this->items)){
    $storedItem = $this->items[$id];
}
```

your code is like: "Ok I already know this item so I will just increment `qty`" because you don't make any difference between ID 1 from `additional_items` and ID 1 from `menu` and this is why you have this strange behavior of added items that are not correct. Obviously, if you add Hamburger (with `ID` to 1) and Fanta (with `ID` to 2), the problem will not show up because there is no ID overriding.

To solve your problem, you have severals solutions:

First, you could just use an UUID in each of your tables so you can share a unique ID across your tables but that's not something really common and to be honest, that would probably lead to others issues later.

Secondly and this solution looks better to me, is to divide your model attribute `$items` in 2 categories (one category per table).

```php
public function add($item, $category){
    $storedItem = ['qty'=>0,'price'=>$item->price,'item'=> $item];
    if($this->items){
        // To avoid undefined error
        if (!array_key_exists($category, $this->items))
            $this->items[$category] = [];
        if(array_key_exists($item->id, $this->items[$category])){
            $storedItem = $this->items[$category][$item->id];
        }
    }
    $storedItem['qty'] ++;
    $storedItem['price'] = $item->price * $storedItem['qty'];
    $this->items[$category][$item->id] = $storedItem;
    $this->totalQty ++;
    $this->totalPrice += $item->price;
}
```

And now you can call your method `add` like that:

```php
$cart->add($product, 'menu');
$card->add($product, 'additional_item');
```

I don't know how you print the cart in your view but obviously, there will be some implications that you will need to solve but it shouldn't be hard.

Comment: it's not working bro i added but it adds one item in one time from one table in session means when i add the value from menu table it adds only menu table items when i clear the session and then i add the items from additional_items table it added but at the same time  when i add items from menu it shows an error menu is undefined

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what's your problem now, can you elaborate ? And for the undefined error, it's just because I didn't try this code but your attribute `item` should have your categories initialised by default or you can do it dynamically in your `add` method. I edited my post to correct that.

Comment: it worked after adding `if (!array_key_exists($category, $this->items))` `$this->items[$category] = [];` but now it does not add multiple items from `menu` and `additional_items` table it adds one item from `menu` and other from `additional_item` table. Actually when use dd function to know the result in `getAddToCart` function i got the static id after adding your code i dont know from where it is coming `+items: array:1 [▼"menu" => array:1 [▼**2** => array:4 [▼"qty" => 1 "price" => 12.0 "id" => 2 "item" => App\Menu {#312 ▶}]] ]+totalQty: 1+totalPrice: 12.0` the main issue is **2** is static

Comment: sorry due to less space i add new comment the main issue with 2 which is written between the stars which is static i think that's why i am unable to add multiple items. `+items: array:1 [▼"menu" => array:1 [▼****2**** => array:4...`